# Error de permisos en RHEL8 al usar move_upload_file

Tags: php

Tengo centos rhel 8, al querer cargar un archivo y moverlo a un directorio dentro de mi carpeta con move_upload_file me lanza un error de permisos

Lei que era cuestion de los permisos en la configuracion de hhttpd.conf pero agregue permisos en httpd.conf para mi usuaripo actual de lammp y no logro que funcione

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En lugar de intentar ubicar el archivo donde sea que lo estes haciendo primero comprueba si puedes hacerlo dentro de la propia estructura de tu web, es decir, en la raiz de tu web o bien en un subdirectorio del mismo que tenga el mismo usuario y grupo que el archivo php.

Comment: No resumas el error, pon el mensaje de error, ojalá como texto, EN la pregunta. Lo otro, pon el código relevante también. Cómo estás intentando usar move_upload_file? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).